# group count Mongo

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Добрый день.

Имеется монго коллекция, в которой содержатся записи вида:

```
[{id: 1, tags: ['tag1', 'tag2']}, {id: 2, tags: ['tag1', 'tag3']}]
```

Я плохо знаю NoSQL, как здесь сделать запрос, возвращающий информацию вида tag1 - столько-то записей, tag2 - столько-то записей?

Т.е. как это в реляционной БД выглядит, понятно. Именно в Монго непонятно.

Comment: У вас документ невалид JSON.

Comment: Тут пример написан, в таблице запись не буквально такая

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте документ

Comment: хорошо, так устроит?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Группирует по тегам и показывает сумму по каждому тегу
   db.coll.aggregate([
      { $unwind: "$tags" },
      { $group: { _id: "$tags", count: { $sum: 1 } } }
   ])
```